# How can I pass an argument to vimrc when I start (g)vim?

Tags: vim

I want to influence how my vimrc file is executed when I start vim and thought of using a global variable like so

```
if exists("g:UseEnv1")
   ....
else
   ....
endif
```

This variable would be set when starting vim like so

```
gvim -c "let g:UseEnv1=1" file-1 file-2
```

However, this doesn't work because the *-c ex commands* are evaluated after the vimrc file is executed.

I could use environment variables

```
if $UseEnv1 == 1
   ...
endif
```

Yet I feel this is a bit problematic in case I forget to change the value of $UseEnv1 between two sessions. Ideally, I'd like to explicitly have to state that I want Env 1 when I start vim.

Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `--cmd` command-line argument is like `-c`, but it is executed *before* any other initialization. You can use that to set certain Vim variables that influence your `~/.vimrc`.

#### Alternatives and their merits

If you plan to actually *type* those configurations in the command-line (vs. coding them into a shell alias or similar), the use of environment variables isn't actually so bad: In most (Unix) shells, you can set variables only for one command by prepending them. So instead of

```
$ gvim --cmd "let g:UseEnv1=1" file-1 file-2
```

you could write

```
$ UseEnv1=1 gvim file-1 file-2
```